# Error: object type cannot be compared with an int

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

This is my table:

```
roomtype, number of rooms
Ac        10
```

I want to retrieve the value from the table and subtract the rooms by 1 and update the above table. How do I write the retrieval code in ASP.NET using C#?

This is the updated code. It is showing errors in `dt.Rows[0]["no_of_rooms"] > 1` saying that an object type cannot be compared with an `int`. But on parsing this no_of_rooms to int the error remains the same.

```
public partial class Book_Room : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string type = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string name = TextBox2.Text;
        string nop = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.ToString();
        int num = int.Parse(nop);
        string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HMSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        string qry3 = "select * from availiability where RoomType=@type";
        SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(qry3, connection);
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", type);
        cmd3.ExecuteReader();
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd3);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {    
            if (dt.Rows[0]["no_of_rooms"] > 1)
            {
                string qry = "insert into RoomType values('" + type + "','" + name + "','" + num + "') ";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, connection);
                connection.Open();
                int g = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (g != 0)
                    Label5.Text = "Reserved for" + name;
                connection.Close();

                string qry2 = "update availiability set RoomType=@type ,availiable_rooms=@av";
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(qry2, connection);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", type);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@av", dt.Rows[0]["no_of_rooms"] - 1);
                connection.Open();
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        else
        {
            label5.Text = "No Rooms Availiable in " + type;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to cast it to an `int` if you want to use it as an `int`.

Comment: It might be just me, but this looks like it's going to transform into some massive spaghetti code eventually.  Instead of having all of your logic in the button click event, delegate the functionality out to helper classes, etc.  Just my two cents.  I just HATE messy code.  I can't help myself.

Answer (score 3):

Change it to this `(int)dt.Rows[0]["no_of_rooms"] > 1`.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can try

`dt.Rows[0].Field<int>("no_of_rooms")>1`

Answer (score 2):

You are not using any of the other values returned from your query, so creating a `SqlDataAdapater` and filling a `Table` is a bit much.

I would recommend using `ExecuteScalar` instead.  This returns a single value from the database.

```
string qry3 = "select * from availiability where RoomType=@type";
SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(qry3, connection);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", type);
object objCount = command.ExecuteScalar();
int count = objCount == null ? 0 : (int)objCount;
if (count > 0)
{
    // Do other things
}
```